# How to change color of the auto-generated nested indicator icon of material-ui's List component?

Tags: javascript, css, list, material-ui, nested-lists

I am having the following Nested list. I want to change the color of the auto generated nested indicator icon. How to do it?

```
<List>
   <ListItem 
     primaryText="My Images" 
     style={{color:'white', width:'100%', fontSize:'14px', marginTop:'27.5%'}} 
     primaryTogglesNestedList={true} 
     nestedItems={[
       <ListItem key={1} primaryText="Drafts"/>,
     ]}
   />
   <ListItem primaryText="My Profile" style={{color:'white', width:'100%', fontSize:'14px'}}/>
   <ListItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white', width:'100%', fontSize:'14px'}}/>
   <ListItem primaryText="Personal Information" style={{color:'white', width:'100%', fontSize:'14px'}}/>
</List>
```